# Тень вверху UITableView не появляется

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Пытаюсь сделать тень сверху tableView, вот код:

```
tableView.layer.masksToBounds = false
tableView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
tableView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -5.0, height: -5.0)
tableView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
```

Так же пробовал ставить `CGSize.zero`, но тень по прежнему не показывается.

Вот что я хочу:

[image: вот что должно получится]

Comment: Это часом не ячейка на картинке?

Comment: @VAndrJ нет, это начало UITableView над ней выше обычный UIView

Comment: По виду просто CardView напоминает. Странно что не добавляется. Должна. Xоть и не такая как на картинке. Где Вы добавлете это?

Comment: @VAndrJ  в viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: А как сами элементы размещали? Можете приложить проект где воспроизводится проблема?

Comment: @VAndrJ https://yadi.sk/i/MG0EXnXY3MAyxj